# ng2-smart-table : custom img css

Tags: angular

i used  ng2-smart-table to display data but the image show off  too big [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEuUl.png) 
i want to change img width to 100%

**Component.ts**

```
  public settings = {
    actions: {
      position: 'right'
    },
    columns: {
      image: {
        title: 'image',
        type: 'html',
        valuePrepareFunction: (value) =>
      { return '<img style="width: 100%" src= ' + value + '  />' },
      },
      title: {
        title: 'Title'
      },
      date: {
        title: 'Date & Hour'
      },
      stat: {
        title: 'Status',
        type: 'html',
      },
      description: {
        title: 'Description',
      }

    },
    attr: {
      class: 'table img-fluid'
    },
  };
```

thank you